# Getting exact font sizes with relsize

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontsize, relsize

I'm fine-tuning the presentation of a book written using XeLaTeX, ready to send to the printers.   The book has lots of tables which are all formatted in the same way. In one, column headings are just a little too wide, and I'd like to tweak the font size just a tiny bit to give a little more space around them without making them obviously smaller.  I'm trying to use `\textscale` from the [`relsize`](https://ctan.org/pkg/relsize?lang=en) package to do this, but I'm finding it doesn't allow arbitrary scaling of the font.  Here's a MWE showing this:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{relsize}

\begin{document}
Test
\textscale{0.95}{Test}
\textscale{0.85}{Test}
\textscale{0.849}{Test}
\end{document}
```

When I compile this using `xelatex`, the second and third "Test" appear to be the same size, while there's a noticeable difference between the third and fourth, despite the fact the third should be more than 10% smaller than the second, while the fourth should be barely 0.1% smaller which ought not to be perceptible.  Viewing the PDF output, it appears these are being rounded to 10pt, 9pt, 9pt and 8pt, respectively.  Is there a way of achieving this without rounding?

Comment: the relsize package seems mainly focussed on picking one of the standard sizss, `\small`, `\tiny` etc that is closest to the requested size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`relsize` is picking the nearest standard size `\small` or `\footnotesize` so  you are getting the same size in two cases. The much simpler `scalefnt` package just does what you ask.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{scalefnt}
\showoutput
\begin{document}
Test
\scalefont{0.95}{Test}
\scalefont{0.85}{Test}
\scalefont{0.849}{Test}
\end{document}
```

Note that visually you still see a difference around 8.5pt as you are changing fonts, the default declaration for `lm` is

```
\DeclareFontShape{TU}{lmr}{m}{n}%
  {<-5.5>    \UnicodeFontFile{lmroman5-regular}{\UnicodeFontTeXLigatures}
   <5.5-6.5> \UnicodeFontFile{lmroman6-regular}{\UnicodeFontTeXLigatures}
   <6.5-7.5> \UnicodeFontFile{lmroman7-regular}{\UnicodeFontTeXLigatures}
   <7.5-8.5> \UnicodeFontFile{lmroman8-regular}{\UnicodeFontTeXLigatures}
   <8.5-9.5> \UnicodeFontFile{lmroman9-regular}{\UnicodeFontTeXLigatures}
   <9.5-11>  \UnicodeFontFile{lmroman10-regular}{\UnicodeFontTeXLigatures}
   <11-15>   \UnicodeFontFile{lmroman12-regular}{\UnicodeFontTeXLigatures}
   <15-> \UnicodeFontFile{lmroman17-regular}{\UnicodeFontTeXLigatures}
   }{}
```

so in the last two you are seeing the 8pt design font and the 9pt design font scaled to more or less 8.5pt in each case.

Comment: Thanks.  I hadn't come across the `scalefnt` package before, but it's exactly what I need.